# Multilevel aggregation with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have multiple records in Elasticsearch in the following format:

```
{ 
  "_id": "<id created by elasticsearch>"
  "trend_id": "5573d345b60c4be1a6337d18ad097d6c",  
  "item_state": 1    
}
```

it is possible to have multiple values of `"item_state"` for the same value of `"trend_id"`.
I want to get count of distinct `"trend_id"` for a max `"item_state"`. So if possible values of `"item_state"` are 1,2,3, then I want:

1: Count(Distinct(trend_id)) where 1 is max item_state (grouped by trend_id)

2: Count(Distinct(trend_id)) where 2 is max item_state (grouped by trend_id)

3: Count(Distinct(trend_id)) where 3 is max item_state (grouped by trend_id)

How can I achieve this?

I tried below query, it groups by `"trend_id"` and finds the maximum `"item_state"` for a `"trend_id"`.

```
POST index-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_group_by_trend_id": {
      "terms": {"field": "trend_id"},
      "aggs": {
        "my_max_states": {
          "max": {"field": "item_state"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to further aggregate these results, and find out that how many times 1 was the maximum, 2 was the maximum and 3 was the maximum.

**Example:**

> {"trend_id": "A", "item_state": 1 }
>
> {"trend_id": "A", "item_state": 2 }
>
> {"trend_id": "A", "item_state": 3 }
>
> {"trend_id": "B", "item_state": 1 }
>
> {"trend_id": "B", "item_state": 1 }
>
> {"trend_id": "C", "item_state": 3 }

**Expected:**

> {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 2}

So Basically I want to run aggregation over the result produced by previous aggregation.